# How to  use the built–in VPN Server on Mac OS 10.6.6

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator, vpn

I know that Mac OS 10.6.6 has a built in VPN server that one can access through command line. Is there an easier way? Can I make an Automator or AppleScript program that starts and stops the built–in VPN server? I have Developer tools installed.

I see that there are several paid software front–ends, like "iVPN", yet I would rather learn how to do this by myself.

The `man` pages are a bit thick for me. But if I could find a step by step walk through then maybe I could parse the `man` pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is what you're after, though I haven't tried it myself.

http://blog.theilluminatedengineer.com/?p=136

Comment: Thanks this is a bit more complex than I thought, yet I am going to give it a shot. I will try to do this for a few days then before I hit something I will go buy "iVPN"...

Comment: There is an old version of iVPN, from back when it was open source, available here. http://tinyapps.org/docs/os_x_vpn_server.html